# Problem in returning 4xx Error in heroku - Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, http-response-codes

I deployed Spring REST API to heroku, in my local environmet for 4xx status code I throw ResponseStatusException and the request get back json of :

```
{
        "timestamp": "2023-01-18T12:20:31.460+00:00",
        "status": 401,
        "error": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Bad credentials",
        "path": "/api/login/employee"
}
```

on heroku I get back from the same request the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-01-18T12:21:54.678+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/login/employee"
}
```

i.e I didnt get the message field in heroku. Its happens to each 4xx error. Why is that and how can I fix it?

I tried to test it on postman when runing in localhost and in heroku. in heroku i didnt get back "message" field

Comment: can you try instead of "message" something like "message123" on heroku? I believe it can return that time. It may be heroku is blocking the "message" field for its own usage

Comment: ResponseStatusException is a class of spring I can't change the field there, but I solved it by creating my own custom exception that return the status. my exception also have a field called message, I dont know why but from my exception is work and with ResponseStatusException it doesn't